# accessing image files from folder in Win 7

Tags: windows-7

windows photo viewer can't open this picture because either photo viewer doesn't have correct permission to access this file location error in win 7 and when trying to open it with paint it showing access denied.How I resolve it?I was given full control but i can't access.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking ownership of the folder. See: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/